# Referencing a Label in Form to change color at ElapsedEventHandler

Tags: c#

So in my `Form1` I have a label called `lblView`

I also have a class called `Timer.cs`

Where I have:

```
public TriageTimer(int ticket_num, int alert_time_in_sec, int error_time_in_sec)
 {
            this.id = ticket_num;

            this.counter.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.count);
            this.counter.Interval = 1000;

            this.alert_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.alert_sound);
            this.alert_timer.Interval = alert_time_in_sec;

            this.error_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.error_sound);
            this.error_timer.Interval = error_time_in_sec;

            this.alert_timer.AutoReset = false;
            this.error_timer.AutoReset = false;

            this.alert_timer.Enabled = true;
            this.counter.Enabled = true;
            this.error_timer.Enabled = true;
 }
```

The primary focus is the

`this.alert_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.alert_sound);`
`this.error_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.error_sound);`

I tried adding:

```
lblView.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

into `alert_sound` but I get the error `lblView` does not exist in the current context. I have looked up this error and found a few answers on stackoverflow that have solutions like; creating a method in the class to write something in the lbl and just call it from the form.

However my question is specifically trying to get the label fontcolor to change when it hits these Events (`alert_sound` & `error_sound`) So is there a way to reference the label that is in `Form1` from `Timer.cs`?

Answer (score 0):

> but I get the error lblView does not exist in the current context.

YES, since the label control instance is present in your FORM, you will have to access it through a reference of that form. You can pass a FORM reference while calling that class method and using that form instance access the label control. Also, the FORM must be opened.